# Move to Last tab on Click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery tabs for my site.Now i want to move to last tab on certain conditions.For that i write some code but didn't work.My tab code is :

```
<div class="wizard">
        <a href="#step1" role="tab" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="current"  style="pointer-events: none;"><span class="hidden-xs">Step</span> 1</a>
        <a href="#step2" role="tab" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab"  style="pointer-events: none;"><span class="hidden-xs">Step</span> 2</a>
        <a href="#step3" role="tab" id="tab3" data-toggle="tab"  style="pointer-events: none;"><span class="hidden-xs">Step</span> 3</a>
        <a href="#step4" role="tab" id="tab4" data-toggle="tab"  style="pointer-events: none;"><span class="hidden-xs">Step</span> 4</a>
      </div>
```

I am trying to move from `step1` to `step4`.I am using this code to move next.I am calling that function like this `change('step1');`.But when i try like this `change('step4');` its not working.It moves to second step instead of 4th.

```
 jQuery('a.btn').each(function () {
      jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass('current');
      jQuery('.wizard a[href="#'+hrf+'"]').click();

  });
```

Some other code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"]').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
      jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass('current');
      jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    });
  });
```

Comment: you dont need a each loop for this, simply remove current class from current a and move to last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to try work around triggering click for moving to a particular tab,

You can use the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option to set a particular tab as active.

You can easily navigate to the last tab by setting active as `-1`.

---

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", -1);
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos..</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any each loop in `Change` function.

```
function change(hrf){
    jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"].current').removeClass('current');
    jQuery('.wizard a[href="#'+hrf+'"]').click();
}
```

**Edited**

Check this code in `bootrap`

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
     e.target // newly activated tab
     e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
});
```

check : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: No i didn't get anything.when i alert before moving it shows me that it is step4.

Comment: how you handle a click event for tabs?

Comment: I have added some new code to question.Check that may it can help

Comment: check my edited code, i think you are using bootsrap, then it is very simple.

Comment: It moves but didn't enable the the tab.Normally moves enable and change color.